# Angular JS for creating a master page child page effect

Tags: angularjs, uiview, routes

I need this Master Page and Child Page functionality in my application that uses HTML and calls Web Apis using AngularJS.

[image: Functionality to be achieved in HTML5 Angular JS]

I'm having a problem in routing in this scenario.

Code used for Routing in Route.js:

```
var MainApp = angular.module('MainApp', ['ngRoute']);
 MainApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../partials/DashboardMenu.html',
        controller: 'DashboardMain'
    })
    .when('/Holidays', {
        templateUrl: '../partials/Holidays.html',
        controller: 'Holidays'
    })
    .when('/Projects', {
        templateUrl: '../partials/Projects.html',
        controller: 'Projects'
    })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
});
```

Dashboard.html

```
<body ng-app="MainApp" ng-controller="DashboardMainController">
<div class="view-animate-container">
    <div ng-view class="view-animate"></div>
</div>
```

DashboardMenu.html

```
<div class="container-fluid btn-group">
<div class="row">
    <a href="../partials/MyProfile.html" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="" alt="My Profile" />
    </a>

    <a href="../partials/Projects.html" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="" alt="Projects List" />
    </a>

    <a href="../partials/Holidays.html" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="" alt="Holidays List" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Below is the folder structure in my application:

[image]

After the User logs in from the Login Page, the user should be redirected to Dashboard.html with the default child view as DashboardMenu.html

In login Service.cs, when I authenticate the User and try to redirect him to the Dashboard.html with the below code snippet, it's just appending the URL with the Dashboard.html.

```
$location.path('DashboardMenu.html')
```

For this, I've added `<base href="/" />` in Dashboard.html and locationProvider.html5mode and hasprefix but nothing worked for me. Please let me know where I'm missing..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to implement some kind of version of nested views with ngRoute, which does not support that. I would suggest using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which has support for nested states.

Answer (score 0):

`$location.path()` should be set to url value that matches in your routing config.....not to the template path

Try changing

```
$location.path('DashboardMenu.html')
```

to

```
$location.path('/')
```

Same with your href values.... should be url not template

Chnge

```
<a href="../partials/Projects.html" class="thumbnail">
```

to

```
<a href="/Projects" class="thumbnail">
```

---

NOTE: Make sure server is configured for using `html5Mode`

---

You also need to remove `ng-controller` from templates that are used by routing that have controller declared already in the routing config. Otherwise you will end up with 2 instances of the controller running

Might suggest you study some more tutorials

Comment: The Code $location.path('DashboardMenu.html') is in loginService,js file. Please refer the folder structure above. I've even changed it to location.path('/'). Also changed the href values as indicated. There are no controllers in template files. Still I'm not able to redirect to Dashboard.html with ngview set to DashboardMenu,html.

Comment: Is server configured for html5mode? I really think you need to spend some more time studying tutorials on how all this works. `path()` will never point to a template file